# Delete commit which had no changes

Tags: git, github, merge

In my git repository I have a commit to merge a branch into master. However the only commit on that branch was added to master before the merge, so the merge changed nothing. There have now been several other commits after the merge.

I would like to delete the merge to make the network graph cleaner.

Network graph:

```
- @a ---- @b ---- @merge --- .... more commits
  |               |
  \------ @b ---- /
```

where `@a` is where the branch was created, `@b` is a commit with content and `@merge` has no changes

The desired state is:

```
- @a ---- @b ---- ... more commits
```

Command `git log --graph --oneline --all` gives:

```
* 1b1076a Add while statement
* 3d7ae6a add logical shortcircuit operators
* 96d0631 add if statement
* a56529e tidy up, add context free grammar file
* 0ba080a add javadoc comments to whole project - yay!
* 5a376b1 Add scoped variables and error when reading uninitialised variable
*   a52e685 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/SparkleCode/Java-Interpreter
|\
| * 6cb6c07 globl variables!
* | 9a1c395 global variables
|/
* 5e5913f fixed netbeans
* 5aecfa8 initialize from old repo
* 8b30840 Initial commit
```

in this log 6cb6c07 committed the same code as 9a1c395, making both 6cb6c07 and a52e685 unnecessary

Comment: Why `@b` is in both branches?

Comment: And.. What is the desired state?

Comment: netbeans did something weird with the commit @b and put it in a branch for some unknown reason, I didn't know what it had done, so I just committed it to master, like I wanted netbeans to do.

Comment: Please run `git log --graph --oneline --all` and paste the result.

Comment: @Opal done, also the repo is at https://github.com/SparkleCode/Java-Interpreter/ if that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you need to do is to rebase but please read my answer till the end before running any commands. Rebasing in git is.. changing the base of a commit - this is a typical operation that is used in day-to-day work. However sometimes - like in this scenario - rebase may result in rewriting the history of git, so changing the commit IDs. This may result in need to push the changes to remote repo with `-f` or `--force-with-lease` switches. And now, if you work alone in a project this should not be a matter. However in a team it will result in incoherent state of remote repo and other users may have they work lost if they are not cautious enough.

That said, current state is:

```
* 1b1076a 2017-11-14 18:22:46 +0000 ScratchOs (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Add while statement
* 3d7ae6a 2017-11-12 17:38:26 +0000 ScratchOs add logical shortcircuit operators
* 96d0631 2017-11-12 14:01:27 +0000 ScratchOs add if statement
* a56529e 2017-11-12 13:42:05 +0000 ScratchOs tidy up, add context free grammar file
* 0ba080a 2017-11-12 12:47:24 +0000 ScratchOs add javadoc comments to whole project - yay!
* 5a376b1 2017-11-09 20:11:48 +0000 ScratchOs Add scoped variables and error when reading uninitialised variable
*   a52e685 2017-11-08 20:47:52 +0000 ScratchOs Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/SparkleCode/Java-Interpreter
|\  
| * 6cb6c07 2017-11-08 20:45:12 +0000 ScratchOs globl variables!
* | 9a1c395 2017-11-08 20:45:12 +0000 ScratchOs global variables
|/  
* 5e5913f 2017-11-08 20:02:43 +0000 ScratchOs fixed netbeans
* 5aecfa8 2017-11-08 16:40:17 +0000 ScratchOs initialize from old repo
* 8b30840 2017-11-08 16:31:54 +0000 William Moreton Initial commit
```

You need to rebase - change the parent of commit `a52e685` so you need to run:

```
git rebase 9a1c395
```

Which results in:

```
 /tmp/Java-Interpreter/ [master] git rebase 9a1c395
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: globl variables!
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   src/sparklecode/AstPrinter.java
M   src/sparklecode/Expr.java
M   src/sparklecode/Interpreter.java
M   src/sparklecode/Parser.java
M   src/tool/generateAst.java
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.
Applying: Add scoped variables and error when reading uninitialised variable
Applying: add javadoc comments to whole project - yay!
Applying: tidy up, add context free grammar file
Applying: add if statement
Applying: add logical shortcircuit operators
Applying: Add while statement
```

And the new state is:

```
* b909b74 2017-11-14 18:22:46 +0000 ScratchOs (HEAD -> master) Add while statement
* 53b9e9b 2017-11-12 17:38:26 +0000 ScratchOs add logical shortcircuit operators
* 9df0bd6 2017-11-12 14:01:27 +0000 ScratchOs add if statement
* 4795c73 2017-11-12 13:42:05 +0000 ScratchOs tidy up, add context free grammar file
* 43d4cdf 2017-11-12 12:47:24 +0000 ScratchOs add javadoc comments to whole project - yay!
* 8323a42 2017-11-09 20:11:48 +0000 ScratchOs Add scoped variables and error when reading uninitialised variable
| * 1b1076a 2017-11-14 18:22:46 +0000 ScratchOs (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Add while statement
| * 3d7ae6a 2017-11-12 17:38:26 +0000 ScratchOs add logical shortcircuit operators
| * 96d0631 2017-11-12 14:01:27 +0000 ScratchOs add if statement
| * a56529e 2017-11-12 13:42:05 +0000 ScratchOs tidy up, add context free grammar file
| * 0ba080a 2017-11-12 12:47:24 +0000 ScratchOs add javadoc comments to whole project - yay!
| * 5a376b1 2017-11-09 20:11:48 +0000 ScratchOs Add scoped variables and error when reading uninitialised variable
| *   a52e685 2017-11-08 20:47:52 +0000 ScratchOs Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/SparkleCode/Java-Interpreter
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 6cb6c07 2017-11-08 20:45:12 +0000 ScratchOs globl variables!
* | 9a1c395 2017-11-08 20:45:12 +0000 ScratchOs global variables
|/  
* 5e5913f 2017-11-08 20:02:43 +0000 ScratchOs fixed netbeans
* 5aecfa8 2017-11-08 16:40:17 +0000 ScratchOs initialize from old repo
* 8b30840 2017-11-08 16:31:54 +0000 William Moreton Initial commit
```

Notice that above commit `9a1c395` hashes have changed and the state of the repository `HEAD -> master` vs `(origin/master, origin/HEAD)` is incoherent. Now you need to push the changes:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```